# Pandas dataframe - select elements based on list of values for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ['A','A','A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'C2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'C3': [2., 3.1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.1, .4, .5]
})
```

I would like to filter the dataframe for individual combinations on C1 and C2.

For example, I would like to have the combination for the following matches:
(C1 == 'A' & C2 == 2) and
(C1 == 'B' & C2 == 1).

The resulting data frame should look as follows:

```
   C1   C2  C3
0   A   2   3.1
1   B   1   1.4
```

So, I would like to filter on the unique combinations, e.g. given by a list of tuples. For the above example it would look like this:

```
[('A', 2), ('B', 1)]
```

Can you guide me how I can accomplish this ideally not using a loop?

Thank you.

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try [`MultiIndex.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html) to create a boolean mask which can be used to filter the rows

```
df[df.set_index(['C1', 'C2']).index.isin(l)]
```

Alternative approach with `merge`

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['C1', 'C2']))
```

---

```
  C1  C2   C3
1  A   2  3.1
3  B   1  1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ['A','A','A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'C2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'C3': [2., 3.1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.1, .4, .5]
})
df[df[["C1","C2"]].apply(tuple, 1).isin([('A', 2), ('B', 1)])]
```

|  | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | 3.1 |
| 3 | B | 1 | 1.4 |